# How to plot an arrow into one of the subplots?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to control to which subplot should the arrow be drawn, please? Now it is in the second one, how to assign it to the first one?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,3))
ax1.set_xlim(0, 0.05)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 1500)

style="Simple,tail_width=0.5,head_width=4,head_length=8"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style, color='black')
a3 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (0.01, 500),connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.3", **kw)
for a in [a3]:
    plt.gca().add_patch(a)

plt.show()
```

Comment: (1) `cfg` is never defined. (2) In what way does this fail? Do you get an error? Please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I editted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the patch directly to the axis:

```
# for a in [a3]:
#    plt.gca().add_patch(a)
ax1.add_patch(a3)
```

Output:

[image]